# Automation of Oracle cloud application (like OTM,CPQ, WHM etc)

Tags: tms, warehouse

Can we automate any of these application using open source (like Test project or selenium, Javascript or cypress)
• WMS (Warehouse Management)
• TMS (Transportation Management)
• Leasing
• EPM (Enterprise Performance Management)
• CPQ (Configure Price Quote)

if yes please guide me with resources

Answer (score 0):

Open source software is created with intention to contribute to a community of users, not companies.

I can not think of software solutions like the ones mentioned created open source, they are very big. Who would create a big solution for a big corporation for free?
Thinking the other way around, companies that runs this kind of software needs support and guarantees, so making their finance or logistics to depend on a software that can be phased out tomorrow does not make sense from a business perspective.

I think that perhaps your needs are not as high as the kind of software referred, or you are asking to cut costs where I am afraid it is not possible, or if possible, perhaps not worth.